# Import another gruntjsfile into a gruntjsfile along with the tasks?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a gruntjsfile.js in the root.
I also have gruntjsfiles.js in the subfolders of the root.
Can you import tasks from the gruntfiles that is the subfolder into main gruntjsfile in the root and vice versa?

I separated tasks into different files to make it clean, but at the root i need to execute tasks from different subroot gruntfiles.

Can i do like import('test/gruntjsfile') and get tasks? or something familiar?

Directory

- Root (Gruntfile.coffee

  - dev root (Gruntfile.coffee)
  - prod root (Gruntfile.coffee)

So i want to get tasks from dev root gruntfile and use them in Root gruntfile.

```
//root Gruntfile.coffee
module.exports = (grunt) ->
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)
grunt.task.loadTasks('./devroot/')
grunt.initConfig
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
grunt.registerTask 'test', ['watch:tests']

//dev root (gruntjs)
module.exports = (grunt) ->
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)
grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    coffee:
        engine:
            compile:
                expand : true
                cwd: 'theme/configurator/src/'
                src:['*.coffee']
                dest: 'theme/configurator/src/'
                ext: '.js'
        tests:
            compile:
                expand : true
                cwd: 'drupal/unit_tests/test_cases/coffee/'
                src:['*.coffee']
                dest: 'unit_tests/test_cases/js/'
                ext: '.js'
    jshint:
        options:
            asi: true
            eqnull: true
            sub: true
            browser: false
            phantom: true
            eqeqeq: true
        files:
            src: ['theme/configurator/src/*.js']
    uglify:
        jsfiles:
            options:
                compress:{}
                beautify: true
                report: 'min'
                sourceMap: false
                sourceMapIncludeSources: false
                exportAll: false
            files: [
                expand: true, 
                cwd: 'drupal/theme/configurator/src/', 
                src:'*.js', 
                dest:'drupal/theme/configurator/src/']
    watch:
        tests:
            options:
                livereload: true
                forever: true
                atBegin: false
            testcoffeefiles:
                files: ['unit_tests/test_cases/coffee/*']
                tasks: ['newer:coffee:tests']
            enginefiles:
                files: ['theme/configurator/src/*.coffee']
                tasks: ['newer:coffee:engine']
```

Comment: Did you took a look at http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#loading-externally-defined-tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can load them from a `path`

```
grunt.task.loadTasks(tasksPath)
```

The complete reference is [here](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#loading-externally-defined-tasks).

If you want you can add them programmatically by searching in the folder hierarchy below current directory.

You could also execute `grunt` in a task.

Another option is to use [`grunt-run-grunt`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-run-grunt) is one option,[`grunt-grunt`](https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-grunt) is another.

Comment: can I add multiple files into loadTasks?

Comment: hi i updated the question with code. I tried your step but it doesn't work. Can you take a look at it agian? thx